# Update CSS onDomReady for nested checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some nested checkboxes that are loading correct data from the database, however I would like to put a line through the text label for the ones that are checked. It's working fine for the second level checkboxes, but I haven't been able to make the first level checkboxes work fine.

**You can see the bug here:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/Zfv7h/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-finalized").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
     $(this).closest("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }
    });
  $(".subchapter-finalized").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      $(this).closest("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Change your Javascript to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.content-finalized:checkbox:checked").next('span').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $("input.subchapter-finalized:checkbox:checked").parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

I had to slightly change your html markup. All I did was wrap the Chapter in a .
Here's why. When I applied the css line-though to the parent `<li>`, it also applied it to it's children even though I specified the text-decoration to none for unchecked elements. So, now instead of applying it to the parent `<li>`, I'm applying it to the `<span>` instead.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfv7h/7/)

Comment: May be I didn't explain myself right and I apologize for that but, that's what I'd like to avoid to happen.... notice that Chapters 1.2 and 3.2 are not checked but they still have a line through...

Comment: @met.lord Still not sure I understand even after reading the question again... So you only want the checked checkboxes to have the line-through?